# Link issue in modal window on video page of mobile website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, modal-dialog

I have a mobile video website and i want to display a modal window on the video page. This modal window will display while video pause. Inside the modal, it has a link. "My problem is, the link cannot be click after the video paused." I have no idea how to fix it but it seems like it's css problem.

```
#lean_overlay {
position: fixed;
z-index:100;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background: #000;
display: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/asBPR/3/

In this demo, it works fine on web browsers. So please use your mobile device to visit the page and click to play the video then pause. After paused, click the link above the player to display the modal window. You will see a link inside the modal, try touch the link to open it.

P.S: I tested on my iPhone 4 only.